# Reverse a 2D array in C

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, reverse, function-definition

I'm trying to reverse my 2D array, I have this code with two functions, first one creates a random matrix of a rows and a columns, the second one must reverse it, but I don't quite understand what I did wrong there, because in the end it prints me just a row of numbers. Example: last number in the matrix is, let's say, 12, so it prints me: " 0 12 0 "

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int ar[100][100];

void create_mat(int a)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j=0; j<a; j++)
        {
            ar[a][a]=rand()%15+1;
            printf("%d\t", ar[a][a]);
        }
    }
}
void reverse_mat(int a)
{
    printf("\nReversed: ");
    for (int i=0; i<a/2; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j=0; j<a; j++)
        {
            int temp = ar[a][a];
            ar[a][a]=ar[a-i-1][a];
            ar[a-i-1][a]=temp;
            printf("%d\t", ar[a][a]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int (*funcptr)(int);
    int (*rev)(int);
    funcptr = &create_mat;
    rev = &reverse_mat;
    int a;
    printf("Introduce the number of rows and columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    funcptr(a);
    rev(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you complicating this with function pointers?

Comment: If you're only ever printing `ar[a][a]`, with `a` never changing, why do you expect the whole thing to be printed?

Comment: Note that the function pointer variables doesn't match the functions you assign to them.

Comment: @klutt getting myself familiar with pointer to function

Comment: Also think about something like `ar[a][a]=rand()%15+1;`... Try to explain it (and the loop it's in) to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Especially the indexing.

Comment: Please turn your code into a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example.  Remove that which is not necessary to your problem.  In this case, function pointers, user-input (scanf), and random values are not integral to the question at hand, and make more work in finding the problem.

Comment: @Vlad You are using invalid indices. For example ar[a][a]=rand()%15+1; instead of using i and j.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow oi lmao didn't even notice it xd, thank you

Comment: @Vlad These lines     int (*funcptr)(int);
    int (*rev)(int);
    funcptr = &create_mat;
    rev = &reverse_mat; do not make a sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone for your help! Due to my pause in coding for a month, I've commited some errors that led to my problems, such as ar[a][a], rand()%15+1, etc. With your help and hints I fixed the program, and now it is doing what I was wanting it to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int ar[100][100];

void create_mat(int a)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j=0; j<a; j++)
        {
            ar[i][j]=rand()%16;
            printf("%d\t", ar[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
void reverse_mat(int a)
{
    for (int i=0; i<a/2; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j=0; j<a; j++)
        {
            int temp = ar[i][j];
            ar[i][j]=ar[a-i-1][j];
            ar[a-i-1][j]=temp;
        }
    }
}

void print_reversed(int a)
{
    printf("\nMatricea in forma inversa: ");
    for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j=0; j<a; j++)
        {

            printf("%d\t", ar[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int (*funcptr)(int);
    int (*rev)(int);
    int (*ptr_rev)(int);
    funcptr = &create_mat;
    rev = &reverse_mat;
    ptr_rev = &print_reversed;
    int a;
    printf("Introduceti nr de linii si coloane: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    funcptr(a);
    rev(a);
    ptr_rev(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, there is an error in the logic when generating the matrix. Although the print result looks good, you are not assigning the random value to correct locations in the matrix. To avoid this sort of confusion, it is  better to separate the printing logic in a new function.

Second, you were doing something similar for the reverse function. Make sure the values are assigned to the right location in the matrix.

```c
void print_matrix(int a)
{
    printf("\n*********************\n");
    for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<a; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", ar[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void reverse_mat(int a)
{
    printf("\nReversed: ");
    for (int i=0; i<a/2; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<a; j++)
        {
            int temp = ar[i][j]; // this line had the error
            ar[i][j]=ar[a-i-1][j]; // this line had the error
            ar[a-i-1][j]=temp; // this line had the error
        }
    }
}
void create_mat(int a)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<a; j++)
        {
            ar[i][j]=rand()%15+1; // this line had the error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters these lines of code

```
int (*funcptr)(int);
int (*rev)(int);
funcptr = &create_mat;
rev = &reverse_mat;
```

are redundant and moreover types of the pointers are not compatible with the function types of the functions assigned to the pointers due to different return types.

In for loops you are always using incorrect indices. For example within the function `create_mat` there are nested loops

```
for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for (int j=0; j<a; j++)
    {
        ar[a][a]=rand()%15+1;
        printf("%d\t", ar[a][a]);
    }
}
```

where you are using as an index the variable `a` that denotes the size of the matrix instead of using the variables `i` and `j`.

```
for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for (int j=0; j<a; j++)
    {
        ar[i][j]=rand()%15+1;
        printf("%d\t", ar[i][j]);
    }
}
```

If the value of the variable `a` is an odd number then within the function `reverse_mat` elements of the middle row will not be reversed due to the condition in the outer loop

```
for (int i=0; i<a/2; i++)
```

where you again are using invalid indices.

The program can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N   100

int a[N][N];

void create_mat( size_t n, int max_value )
{
    srand( time( NULL ) );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() % max_value + 1;
        }
    }
}

void reverse_mat( size_t n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0, j = n * n; i < --j; i++ )
        {
            int tmp = a[ i / n] [ i % n ];
            a[ i / n ][ i % n ] = a[ j / n][ j % n ];
            a[ j / n][ j % n ] = tmp;
        }
    }       
}

void display( size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%2d ", a[i][j] );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 0;
    
    printf( "Introduce the number of rows and columns: " );
    
    scanf( "%zu", &n );
    
    if ( N < n ) n = N;
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    create_mat( n, 15 );
    display( n );
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    reverse_mat( n );
    display( n );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Introduce the number of rows and columns: 3

10  4 14 
12 14  7 
 6  8  3 

 3  8  6 
 7 14 12 
14  4 10
```